# Quadratic form positive definite if limits are positive infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let
$$q(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}{x_i}{x_j}, \quad a_{ij}\in \mathbb{R}.$$
be a quadratic form with real coefficients. Suppose that 
$$ \lim_{x_i \rightarrow \pm \infty} q(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = + \infty$$
for every $i$ while the remaining variables are fixed. Is it true that $q$ is necessarily positive definite?

Comment: Take $x^2-1$, is it positive definite?

Comment: it's not a quadratic form

Comment: Silly me, you are of course right, but it doesn't matter, take $x^2-4xy+y^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the form $$q(x,y)=x^2+3y^2+4xy$$

In fact this is the form $$q(\bar x,\bar y)=\bar x^2-\bar y^2$$ in the basis $(1,0), (2,1)$.